I uploaded a paper on ArXiv, but it's not showing me as an author in Google Scholar
I published a preprint in ArXiv recently, but when I search for it in Google Scholar, my name is not being shown up, it only shows the other co-authors. Why does this happen? How do I fix that?
Thank you!

Metadata error? Are you correctly listed as an author on arXiv itself (i.e. not the PDF of the paper)?

What is "correctly listed"? Same as the ORCID? Do you know how Google Scholar does the cross-ref? Thank you.
